# KQL Script to Count Vulnerabilities Over a Time Period

Tags: kql, microsoft365-defender

I'm looking for assistance with a KQL script to count vulnerabilities in Microsoft Defender over a specific time period. I've tried the following script, but I'm encountering some issues:

```
DeviceTvmSoftwareVulnerabilities
| where Timestamp >= datetime(2024-01-01) and Timestamp < datetime(2024-02-01) 
| summarize VulnerabilityCount = count() by DeviceId, VulnerabilityTitle
```

However, I'm getting errors regarding the "Timestamp" column.

Additionally, I've noticed that the reports in Microsoft Defender do not include a specific report to show the total number of vulnerabilities over a period of time. If anyone has any insights or suggestions on how to generate this report, I would greatly appreciate it.

Best regards,

I've been running different KQL scripts, but unusefully.

Comment: What is the error message?